# JavaScript animate absolute positioned elements from bottom to each original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have several `absolute` positioned elements inside a relative positioned container and I am trying to animate them:

From: 200px below their starting DOM position

To: starting DOM position

I have tried the `.animate()` function but I have only succeeded doing the opposite animation.

Edit: What I mean is that I am trying to animate the transition of the elements when the page is loaded.

Comment: We can't help you fix your issues without seeing the relevant HTML/CSS or JS. Please edit your question to include them

Comment: @PraveenKumar not sure you've chosen the right duplicate there. The OP mentions nothing about dragging the items; they're attempting to animate them. Was there another question you were trying to use as a dupe target?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Umm, may be the way it is written now, looks like that solution might help. Or is it not? Feel free to reopen once the question is edited with necessary details?

Comment: I'll leave it for now until the OP clarifies what they're attempting to do

Comment: @vchan Please add a [mcve]. I have reopened your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with CSS keyframes.

```
.elementsClass{
    transform: translateY(200px);
    animation: moveUp 0.8s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes moveUp {
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveUp {
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes moveUp {
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Now the elements are loaded 200px below their starting position and appear at their original position.

Comment: Take a look at https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ it provides a lot of nice CSS animations.